# Queue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an PHP developer, i've never used python before, now i'm implementing am SMS system on our project, it's already working, but as i dont like python i've just made a little script with some information i collected over the web and i call this script using an php, the python script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib, sys
import serial
import time

for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg == "-t":
        recipient = sys.argv[2] # numero
    elif arg == "-m":
        message = sys.argv[4] # mensagem



phone = serial.Serial("/dev/serial0",  9600, timeout=5)
try:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    phone.write(b'ATZ\r')
    time.sleep(0.12)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
    time.sleep(0.12)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGS="' + recipient.encode() + b'"\r')
    time.sleep(0.12)
    phone.write(message.encode() + b"\r")
    time.sleep(0.12)
    phone.write(bytes([26]))
    time.sleep(0.12)
finally:
    phone.close()
    print('OK')
```

And i call it passing the vars on php like:

```
$recipient = "+5511anyphonenumber";
$message = "'Estou fazendo um teste'";
$command = "python3 teste2.py -t $recipient -m $message";
exec($command);
```

The only problem is that i need the script to run only once per 3 seconds, so if it is called once and is called again 2 seconds after, i need the second call to be queued until 3 seconds has been passed from the last call, is there any easy way to do this? Please take in count that i'm not familiar with python.

Comment: That argument parsing is broken, by the way - if you pass in the arguments in the wrong order, they'll get misassigned. (Consider using the argparse module.)

Answer (score 0):

I take it the 3 seconds is just an arbitrary duration it takes for the program has finished doing its thing, not a hard limit?

You'll probably want to use a lock file of some sort to avoid concurrent executions. Take a look at [`fasteners`](https://pypi.org/project/fasteners/) (as suggested in the now-deprecated [`lockfile`](https://pypi.org/project/lockfile/)); it's designed to do things right (there are certain race-condition/atomicity corner cases you need to take care of if you decide to roll your own.)

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look on this.

Comment: why would you recommend a deprecated library to a beginner ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list (something like an array) to store any calls that come during the 3 seconds. As the calls come, append them to the list (use the append() method - `<list>.append(<object>)` 
 ).
After, 3 seconds are over, execute the first element of the list: `<list>[0]` and remove it from the list:

```
<item> = <list>.pop(0)
```

(You can execute the `<item>`)
If you want to accept calls simultaneously during the three seconds while other processes are going, then, use the threading module to accept the calls while running the original process and to store these calls to execute after 3 seconds.

Comment: Not sure how a call can be stored if i close the connection with the script and call it again the stored vars will be lost...

Comment: I think you can use threading ( a module) for that. With that, you can perform simultaneous processes - (1) record the calls and (2) perform whatever you were doing at the same time. But, you may have to use some other form of input mechanism or a GUI for input. I am not too sure of the context, so, this is the best answer I would be able to give.